# How to stop google or any search engine indexing the site images?

Tags: html, css, web-crawler

How can I stop crawlers such Google crawlers or any search engine crawlers to not index the images from a particular web page?

Comment: This question is a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Adrift sorry for posting this inappropriate question . It will never happen again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To prevent images from your site appearing in Google's image search
>   results, add a robots.txt file to the root of the server that blocks
>   the image.
>
> For example, if you want Google to exclude the dogs.jpg image that
>   appears on your site at www.yoursite.com/images/dogs.jpg, add the
>   following to your robots.txt file:
>
> User-agent: Googlebot-Image Disallow: /images/dogs.jpg
>
> The next time Google crawls your site, we'll see this directive and
>   drop your image from our search results.
>
> To remove all the images on your site from our index, place the
>   following robots.txt file in your server root:
>
> User-agent: Googlebot-Image Disallow: /

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35308

first link on google

Comment: Right but this only works for google, what about other search engine ?